# In AWS IoT Rules, can't target Alias/Version for Step Function action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-step-functions, aws-iot

I am attempting to:

- Route some messages from an AWS IoT Topic to a Step Function using [Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rules.html)
- Choose a specific [Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-state-machine-alias.html) to run for that Step Function

However, in the AWS Console (web interface) you can only select the "State machine". There aren't any further options for versions or alias's.

Is it possible to target a specific version or alias from the AWS IoT Rules actions?

[image: screenshot of rule action editor]